# C++ Pointers, Unable To Read Memory

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

Why, when I initiate my pointer, I can read the assigned value:

```
DWORD *pBytesReturned = new DWORD[0];
_result =  EnumProcesses(pProcessIds, 1000, pBytesReturned);
```

[image]

But when I initialize it like this I can't read the assigned value:

```
DWORD *pBytesReturned = 0;
_result =  EnumProcesses(pProcessIds, 1000, pBytesReturned);
```

[image]

Here's the complete code if needed:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Psapi.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    bool _result;
    DWORD *pProcessIds = new DWORD[1000];
    DWORD cb;
    DWORD *pBytesReturned =0;
    _result =  EnumProcesses(pProcessIds, 1000, pBytesReturned);
}
```

Comment: You're passing an uninitialized pointer to the function.  What it wants is a pointer to an actual `DWORD` it can write data to, like `&cb`.  There's an example of how to use `EnumProcesses` correctly on the [MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It's worth noting that you must always check the return values for Windows API functions to make sure they succeeded.

Comment: Why is the second one considered uninitialized? Am I not passing a value to the pointer?

Comment: @Pedrumj you're passing the value **of** a pointer, which is NULL. (the `= 0;` initializer). You are correct that you *are* passing a deterministic NULL. Whether that is appropriate for the function is another matter (and it isn't).

Comment: A NULL pointer is not a pointer to a DWORD.

Comment: isn't "pBytesReturned" the pointer and "*pBytesReturned" the value the pointer is referring to? so "pBytesReturned" should be the address while "*pBytesReturned" should be the value NULL?

Comment: When `pBytesReturned == NULL`, `*pBytesReturned = <some number>` would be undefined behavior and in many cases would just crash.  If you're lucky the function checks for a null pointer before writing to it and just fails.  Since you don't check the return value you wouldn't know that.  The text of both your examples is identical, so I don't know what you think the difference is.  If there is a difference you should edit one of them.

Comment: ah I see. Well put it up as an answer and I'll upvote you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intent of the function

```
BOOL
WINAPI
EnumProcesses (
    _Out_writes_bytes_(cb) DWORD * lpidProcess,
    _In_ DWORD cb,
    _Out_ LPDWORD lpcbNeeded
    );
```

is to have a pointer as a third parameter, and this pointer must point to a valid memory location where the function will be storing a dword. The expected function call should look like this

```
DWORD *pProcessIds = new DWORD[1000];
DWORD bytesReturned = 0;
bool _result = EnumProcesses(pProcessIds, 1000, &bytesReturned);
```

or like this

```
DWORD *pProcessIds = new DWORD[1000];
DWORD *pBytesReturned = new DWORD[1];
bool _result = EnumProcesses(pProcessIds, 1000, pBytesReturned);
```

but you should not be using a NULL pointer and expect the debugger to dereference it.

Comment: I'd remove the extra asterisks, they just make your example look confusing.

Comment: @Pedrumj Just as an aside, whenever you see a statically sized dynamic allocation you should remove it unless the allocation size is inappropriate for the stack or the lifetime of the allocation is not scope based. And if the allocation is really small, such as a single `DWORD`, then even when the lifetime is not scope based you should probably just copy the value around instead of copying a pointer to an allocation around.